# OpenGL light example not working using equivalent code in LWJGL

Tags: java, c, opengl, lwjgl

I am learning the "light.c" example described at http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter05.html

After successfully run the example written in C, I modified it to draw a box instead of a sphere.  After that, I also translated the C code into Java using [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/).  However, the Java version doesn't work at all.

Both the C and Java versions are pasted at https://gist.github.com/stfairy/d2aa2f48a9a5801ae72e

The screenshot below is the expected result (which is generated by the C version, but the Java version only gives a black window)

[image: expected result]

Comment: I don't understand why this receives a downvote as well as a vote to close it.  Please kindly leave a comment here if you think this is inappropriate.

Comment: 90% of your code, is deprecated, please don't use the deprecated OpenGL functions.

Comment: @Vallentin I'm just trying to learn LWJGL using some basic examples. Those functions are deprecated in recent versions of OpenGL, but are not deprecated in LWJGL.  And this is a question for LWJGL.

Comment: I would advice you to learn the new ways instead of learning old and deprecated ways. LWJGL uses OpenGL, so that didn't make sense at all, and if you just OpenGL to use version 3.2 and forward, then a ton of errors will be generated and the program won't be able to run. So yes they are also deprecated in LWJGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting this question to LWJGL forum, I got a response and now I have a fix now.

I figured out it is because I didn't understand how `nio.Buffer` works.  After writing the `values` into the `buffer`, we also need to reset the cursor position by calling `rewind()`, otherwise it is using zeros for the material stuff and the light position.  Final code listed below.

```
private FloatBuffer floatBuffer(float... values) {
    FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(Math.max(4, values.length));
    buffer.put(values);
    return (FloatBuffer) buffer.rewind();
}
```